# How to set first day of week to sunday in Objective C?

Tags: ios, calendar, nsdate

I'm trying to set the calendar to display Sunday as the first day of the week. It is currently set for Monday. Can anyone take a look at this code and fix it?  It is from the Custom Calendar available on GitHub: https://github.com/jubinjacob19/CustomCalendar

Thank You

[Calendar Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYhFV.png)

```
    NSDateComponents *components = [_gregorian components:_dayInfoUnits fromDate:_calendarDate];

components.day = 1;
NSDate *firstDayOfMonth         = [_gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
NSDateComponents *comps         = [_gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:firstDayOfMonth];

NSInteger weekdayBeginning      = [comps weekday];  // Starts at 1 on Sunday
weekdayBeginning -=2;
if(weekdayBeginning < 0)
    weekdayBeginning += 7;                          // Starts now at 0 on Monday

NSRange days = [_gregorian rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit
                               forDate:_calendarDate];
```

Comment: Does the main Calendar app show Sunday as the first day of the week? If so and the calendar library you are trying to use does not, then find a calendar library that wasn't written by a programmer that doesn't understand locales.

Comment: The default calendar does NOT show Sunday as the first day. It shows Monday - see Screen Shot of app. This was the best calendar app/code I came across that actually worked without errors. I contacted the developers of several but no response from them. I don't use swift.

Comment: NO, I mean the Calendar app that comes with iOS, not what you show in the screenshot.

Comment: Calendar app & settings in iOS are set to Sunday as start of week.